# При вводе из консоли, scanf срабатывает когда другой поток пишет в консоль

Tags: linux, c, вывод, ввод

Я пытаюсь написать простой чат на С с использованием разделяемой памяти. После отправки сообщения оно сохраняется в разделяемой памяти. Сигнал о завершении изменения отправляется на процессу-серверу, а процесс-сервер передает сигнал остальным клиентам и они его считывают и выводят в консоль, но тут возникает проблема: клиенты ждут ввода с помощью scanf, вывод в консоль идет через printf, и при выводе сообщения срабатывает scanf и клиент пытается отправить сообщения которого нет. и так повторяется много раз. ка это можно исправить?

**Клиент**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SEGSIZE 100
#define SEM_ID  3000
#define SHM_ID  2002

int shmid;
int semid;

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    char string [25];
} message_t;

void readmes(int sig)
{
    message_t *segptr;

    /* Attach (map) the shared memory segment into the current process */
    if ((segptr = (message_t*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == NULL) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "readmes: %s\n", segptr->string);
}

void getusr2(int sig)
{

}

void sendmes(int serid, int shmid, int semid, char* mes)
{
    struct sembuf sem_lock;
    sem_lock.sem_num = 0;
    sem_lock.sem_op = -1;

    //Блочим семафор  
    semop(semid, &sem_lock, 1);
    fprintf(stdout,"Заняли семафор\n");
    message_t *segptr;
    if ((segptr = (message_t *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == NULL) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Изменяем сообщение
    strcpy(segptr->string, mes);
    fprintf(stderr,"Изменили сообщение\n");

    //Сообщаем об изменении серверу
    kill(serid, SIGUSR2);
    fprintf(stderr,"Сообщаем серверу\n");
    pause();

    struct sembuf sem_unlock;
    sem_unlock.sem_num = 0;
    sem_unlock.sem_op = 1;

    //Освобождаем семафор
    semop(semid, &sem_unlock, 1);
    fprintf(stderr,"Освободили семафор\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int server_pid = atoi(argv[1]);

    //создаем обработчик событий
    static struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = readmes;
    sigfillset(&(act.sa_mask));
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL);

    //создаем обработчик событий
    static struct sigaction act2;
    act2.sa_handler = getusr2;
    sigfillset(&(act2.sa_mask));
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act2, NULL);

    //Посылаем сигнал на сервер
    kill(server_pid, SIGUSR1);

    //Создание сегмента разделяемой памяти
    if ((shmid = shmget(SHM_ID, sizeof(message_t), 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("can not create shared memory segment\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("create shared memory segment\n");      

    //Создание массива семафоров из одного элемента
    if ((semid = semget(SEM_ID, 1, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("can not create semaphore\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("create semaphore\n");

    while(1)
    {
        char mess[25];
        scanf("%s", mess);
        //fgets(mess, sizeof(mess), stdin);
        printf("Message: %s\n", mess);
        if (!mess[0])
            break;
        sendmes(server_pid, shmid, semid, mess);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

**Сервер**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define SEGSIZE 100
#define SEM_ID  3000
#define SHM_ID  2002
#define COUNT   10

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    char string [25];
} message_t;

int clients[COUNT] = {0};
int index = 0;

void adduser(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    printf("client conect: %d\n", info->si_pid);

    if (index>=COUNT)
        kill(info->si_pid, SIGKILL);
    else
        clients[index++] = info->si_pid;
}

void sendmes(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    printf("%d: send message\n", info->si_pid);
    for (int i=0;i<COUNT;i++)
    {
        if(clients[i]==0)
            break;

        if(info->si_pid == clients[i])
            continue;

        kill(clients[i], SIGUSR1);
    }

    kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR2);
}

int main()
{
    //Регистрация обработчика подключения новых пользователей
    static struct sigaction actAddClients;
    actAddClients.sa_sigaction = adduser;
    actAddClients.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigfillset(&(actAddClients.sa_mask));
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &actAddClients, NULL);

    //Регистрация обработчика получения сообщения
    static struct sigaction actSendMes;
    actSendMes.sa_sigaction = sendmes;
    actSendMes.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigfillset(&(actSendMes.sa_mask));
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &actSendMes, NULL);

    int shmid;
    int semid;

    //Создание сегмента разделяемой памяти
    if ((shmid = shmget(SHM_ID, sizeof(message_t), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
    {
        printf("can not create shared memory segment\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("create shared memory segment\n");      

    //Создание массива семафоров из одного элемента
    if ((semid = semget(SEM_ID, 1, 0660 | IPC_CREAT)) < 0)
    {
        printf("can not create semaphore\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("create semaphore\n");
    semctl(semid,0,SETVAL,1);

    printf("My pid: %d\n", getpid());

    printf("Pres Enter to exit\n");

    char c;
    while(c!='\n')
        c = getchar();

    //Удаление массива семафоров
    if (semctl (semid, 0, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0)
    {
        printf("can not delete semaphore\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("delete semaphore\n");

    //Удаление сегмента разделяемой памяти
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Пробовали ошибки обрабатывать?

Comment: во-первых, здесь нет другого потока, сигналы обрабатываются **в том же потоке**, прерывая выполнение и это принципиально; во-вторых, всё это делает обработчик сигнала крайне токсичным: в нём **нельзя** вызывать большинство функций стандартной библиотеки и системных вызовов, в частности, `malloc` и, как следствие, `printf`. Фактически, единственное, что в оных обычно делается — это устанавливается какой-то флаг; в-третьих, `shmat()` достаточно сделать один раз... собственно решение отсюда очевидно — смотреть, какие ошибки возникли при `scanf()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло вынести ввод сообщения в другой поток